# Can't use string as a hash ref..?

Tags: perl, indexer

I'm trying to parse an HTML document for a web indexing program. To do this I'm using [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser).

I'm getting an error on the last line of my first if statement:

```
 if ( $token->[1] eq 'a' ) {
     #href attribute of tag A
     my $suffix = $token->[2]{href};
```

that says `Can't use string ("<./a>") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./indexer.pl line 270, <PAGE_DIR> line 1.`

Is my problem that (the suffix? or `<./a>`?) is a string and needs to be turned into a hash ref?  I looked at other posts that had similar errors.. but I'm still not at all sure about this. Thanks for any help.

```
sub parse_document {

    #passed from input
    my $html_filename = $_[0];

    #base url for links
    my $base_url = $_[1];

    #created to hold tokens
    my @tokens = ();

    #created for doc links
    my @links = ();

    #creates parser
    my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new($html_filename);

    #loops through doc tags
    while (my $token = $p->get_token()) {
        #code for retrieving links
        if ( $token->[1] eq 'a' ) {
            # href attribute of tag A
           my $suffix = $token->[2]{href};

            #if href exists & isn't an email link
            if ( defined($suffix) && !($suffix =~ "^mailto:") ) {
                #make the url absolute
                my $new_url = make_absolute_url $base_url, $suffix;

                #make sure it's of the http:// scheme
                if ($new_url =~ "^http://"){
                    #normalize the url
                    my $new_normalized_url = normalize_url $new_url;

                    #add it to links array
                    push(@links, $new_normalized_url);
                }
            }
        }

        #code for text words
        if ($token->[0] eq 'T') {
            my $text =  $token->[1];

            #add words to end of array
            #(split by non-letter chars)
            my @words = split(/\P{L}+/, $text);
        }
    }

    return (\@tokens, \@links);
}
```

Comment: I would print out some debugging statements to see exactly what it thinks token is via Data::Dumper($token) and also to see what $token->[1] is. It could be a ' or something similar messing up the values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `get_token()` method returns an array where `$token->[2]` is a hash reference containing your `href` only if `$token->[0]` is an S (that is, a start tag).  In this case, you are matching an end tag (where `$token->[0]` is an E). See the [PerlDoc](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm) for details.

To fix, add a

```
next if $token->[0] ne 'S';
```

at the top of your loop.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I could just leave out a check for the start tag since I didn't really understand what it was for.. but I guess using a break is needed here.

Answer (score 2):

`$token->[2]` is a string, not a hash reference.

Do a `print $token->[2]` and you'll see that it is a string containing `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

apparently `$token->[2]` is resolving as a hash reference whose value is `"</a>"`.  Certainly not want you want!

Comment: It's actually that `$token->[2]` is a string (`"</a>"`) and he's trying to *use* it as a hash reference.